# Links in golang comments to reference markdown

Tags: go, hyperlink, markdown, comments

I'm using vs code and want to add a link into golang comment like this:

```
// See reference: [.doc/guide/readme.md#L50]
func whatever() {

}
```

So, the idea it's adding a link in comment, and when I will click on link, take me to readme file to line 50.

There is any way to do this? any external library or something?

Thank you in advance!

I tried vscode extensions like LinkComments but I didn't achieve it

Comment: https://go.dev/doc/comment#links